# SassError: Expected spaces, was tabs

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, electron

I'm using scss for my scoped styles in a vue electron app.
Everytime I try to run the `npm run electron:serve` command, it will show the following error message in windows 11 terminal

`SassError: Expected spaces, was tabs.`

This is my sass code, the error occur into a component where I have the needed markup to create a navbar.

```
#nav 
background-color: white
    #logo 
    width:  30px    
    #preloaderWrapper 
        position:   fixed
        top:    30%
        left:   50%
    #menu-icon 
        font-size:  2em
    #main 
        margin-top: 8em
    #search-box 
        width:  520px
    #theme-switcher 
        width:  600px
    .progress
        margin-top: 35em
```

is there a way to fix this and avoid it can occur everytime I use sass?

Comment: Configure your IDE to replace tabs by spaces?

Comment: @Kapcash at the moment I have a code identation for markup of the vue template that are using tabs. It will be a disaster if I switch back to spaces..